# Infinite retries to consume same message after publishing to DLT topic fails using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

> I have being using this DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer for my error handling since beginning of my project(2.1.1.RELEASE for spring-boot and 2.2.9.RELEASE for spring-kafka) and it was working fine till I did spring boot upgrade to 2.6.9(which internally upgraded spring-kafka - 2.8.7)

Originally my application used to retry for 10 times before discarding that poison pill message and able to consume next messages from that steps onwards.
My scenario to test is if the publishing to DLT topic fails then how my application will behave.
In order to reproduce the scenario Im following below steps

1: Producer is producing the message with avro schema X
2: Consumer is trying to consume the same message with avro schema Y and obviously expected to throw Deserialisation exception
3: Consumer is expected to write this message to DLT topic so that it can move forward with next message but I intentionally placed some fault in my producer properties so that message cannot be written on DLT topic
4: Consumer is expected to retry for 10 times ( default value of retry) and then move forward for next set of messages.

It was all working fine for older version of spring-kafka but I recently upgraded the spring-kafka version and now application is indefinitely trying to consume and retry to write to DLT.

Both my topics have got 4 partitions and 1 replica and my consumer property includes

```
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

```java
public void createListener(final MessageListener<Object, Object> messageListener, String topic, Map<String, Object> props) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setErrorHandler(this.eh());
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setConcurrency(3);
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setRetryTemplate(this.retryTemplate());
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setConsumerFactory(this.consumerFactory(props));
        kafkaConsumerFactory.setRecoveryCallback((context) -> {
            if (context.getLastThrowable().getCause() instanceof RecoverableDataAccessException) {
                return null;
            } else {
                log.error("Non recoverable error thrown!");
                throw new BackboneConsumerException(context.getLastThrowable().getMessage());
            }
        });
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(new String[]{topic});
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        containerProperties.setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer container = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(this.consumerFactory(props), containerProperties);
        container.setErrorHandler(this.eh());
        container.start();
    }


private SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh() {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(this.kafkaTemplate()));
    }
```

```
Logs ->
2022-08-16 23:33:23.292 DEBUG 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2022-08-16 23:33:23.321 DEBUG 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 1 records
2022-08-16 23:33:23.322 DEBUG 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2022-08-16 23:34:23.323 ERROR 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener          : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='456' and payload='byte[94]' to topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT and partition 0:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2022-08-16 23:34:23.324 DEBUG 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.c.KafkaTemplate                    : Failed to send: ProducerRecord(topic=stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT, partition=0, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 122, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-cause-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 97, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 46, 107, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-message, value = [102, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 32, 116, 111, 32, 100, 101, 115, 101, 114, 105, 97, 108, 105, 122, 101, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 49]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-stacktrace, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 118, 97, 58, 49, 52, 56, 56, 41, 10, 9, 97, 116, 32, 111, 114, 103, 46, 97, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 115, 46, 99, 111, 110, 115, 117, 109, 101, 114, 46, 105, 110, 116, 101, 114, 110, 122, 101, 114, 46, 106, 97, 118, 97, 58, 49, 51, 52, 41, 10, 9, 46, 46, 46, 32, 50, 49, 32, 109, 111, 114, 101, 10]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-topic, value = [115, 116, 114, 101, 97, 109, 46, 99, 97, 115, 114, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 46, 118, 49, 46, 48]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-partition, value = [0, 0, 0, 0]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-offset, value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp, value = [0, 0, 1, -126, -88, -98, -48, -92]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp-type, value = [67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-consumer-group, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 49])], isReadOnly = false), key=456, value=[B@45a6af18, timestamp=null)

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2022-08-16 23:34:23.324 ERROR 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer    : Dead-letter publication to stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLTfailed for: stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0-0@1

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:666) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:429) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:647) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.send(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:555) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.sendOrThrow(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:520) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:492) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getRecoveryStrategy(FailedRecordProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getRecoveryStrategy(FailedRecordProcessor.java:161) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandlerAdapter.handleRemaining(ErrorHandlerAdapter.java:141) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2690) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2571) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2441) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2319) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1990) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1357) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1252) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_333]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

2022-08-16 23:34:23.324 ERROR 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler        : Recovery of record (stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0-0@1) failed

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Dead-letter publication to stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLTfailed for: stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0-0@1
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.verifySendResult(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:676) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:659) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.send(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:555) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.sendOrThrow(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:520) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:492) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getRecoveryStrategy(FailedRecordProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordProcessor.getRecoveryStrategy(FailedRecordProcessor.java:161) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandlerAdapter.handleRemaining(ErrorHandlerAdapter.java:141) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2690) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2571) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2441) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2319) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1990) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1357) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1252) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_333]

2022-08-16 23:34:23.324 ERROR 87063 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:208) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandlerAdapter.handleRemaining(ErrorHandlerAdapter.java:141) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2690) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2571) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2441) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2319) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1990) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1366) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1357) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1252) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_333]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_333]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 1
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2707) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.checkDeser(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2754) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2628) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2560) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Please provide logs (edit the question); also you are not really using the framework properly, the container factory should be a `@Bean` so that it is initialized properly - e.g. with event publishers which will then be added to the containers it creates.

Comment: @GaryRussell, Please find the logs

Comment: Also the same code was perfectly working with older spring-kafka version and it was retrying for 10 failure attempts and then move fwd but I dont know what happened after spring-kafka upgrade

Comment: `Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.` - simply means your DLT topic (or the target partition) does not exist. Spring does not provision the DLT automatically (and it has never done so). By default, Spring will send to the same partition as the original record - so the DLT must have at least as many partitions as the original, or you need to provide a custom destination resolver. See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters).

Comment: If you read my description I intentionally reproduced this error "Topic stream.case-management.case-approval-requested.v1.0.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms" by removing some producer properties to see how application will behave and retry and what I observed application is retrying infinite times whereas if I use older version of spring-kafka consumer application will only retry for 10 times and move forward for next message.

Comment: I don't believe that failing to publish to the DLT was ever non-fatal (after some attempts), but 2.2.x is extremely old, so my memory may be fuzzy. In any case, I believe it should never move on to the next one, by default. You could subclass the DLPR and keep track of how many times you tried to publish that record and give up, but I don't think the framework should do that by default.

Comment: If you can provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits different behavior between 2.2.x and 2.8.x then I will take a look. But, as I said, I believe the current behavior is correct.

Comment: @GaryRussell, If the exception is thrown from within the DLPR, it seems there is no way ErrorHandler can handle that. In my case it just keeps looping infinitely, keep trying its retry based on back off policy and after attempts are exhausted, it attempts DLPR again, and then starts the whole cycle again, getting in infinite loop. Is there a way I can abort once the exception occurs inside DLPR and acknowledge record, commit the offset and move to next?

Comment: No, that is the correct operation. If recovery fails, it is retried again. If you want different behavior, create your own recoverer, perhaps one that delegates to the DLPR and takes some other action after a failure.

Answer (score 0):

spring kafka version  2.8+ onwards we can use

```
new DefaultErrorHandler(deadLetterPublishingRecoverer,
                new FixedBackOff(BACKOFF_INTERVAL, MAX_FAILURES))
```

With the above setup, if there is any issue while publishing message to DLT as part of recovery, will lead to repeated action of publishing DLT with never ending loop.
To resolve the repeated loop issue we can set

```
deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.setFailIfSendResultIsError(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Above will make sure NOT to fail recovery operation if publishing to DLT fails. This will make sure to ack the poison record so that consumer can go ahead with next offsets.